# When reading input from the user in Perl, how to let Perl not display "Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)"?

Tags: perl, input, io

I'm very new to Perl and currently I'm learning it on Windows 7 with ActiveState Perl. This is my program.

```
chomp(my @lines = <STDIN>);

foreach (sort @lines) {
    print $_;
}
```

When running the program, I type some lines of strings then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to tell the program that I've finished typing. However, after I get my result (generated from `print $_;`), I also got this message: **Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)**. How to disable this message?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to perl!  Please `use strict` and `use warnings` as you find your way around.  You'll appreciate it later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows, to signify End of Line press `Ctrl + Z` followed by `Enter`

Pressing `Ctrl + C` sends the interrupt signal to your program which is the cause of the `Terminating on SIGINT` message you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (EOF) instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can handle signals like that:

```
$SIG{INT} = sub { print("Caught SIGINT but continue!\n"); };
```

for a keyboard interrupt. It's an exemple.